# Url accessed with success from browser but fails with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring

as a fresh starter with angular i need your help, i can access a url manually with browser but with angular it gives me url not found i have an angular js service designed as follow

```js
App.factory('SsCategorieMere', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource(
      location.href.split('#')[0]+"/ac477c79d1677a43496823c2a58a2f68sscategoriesMeres",
            {},
            {
                update: {
                      method: 'PUT' // Mise á jour avec la méthode PUT de HTML
                }

            }
    );
}]);
```

and my angular controller :

```js
'var strict';

App.controller('InputTextController',['$scope', 'InputText','SsCategorieMere',function($scope, InputText,SsCategorieMere){

     var self=this;
     self.InputText=new InputText();
     self.ssCategoriesMeres=[];

     self.addContent= function(){
         self.InputText.$save();
     }

     self.ssCategoriesMeres=SsCategorieMere.query();


}]);
```

my Rest controller with spring like like follow

```html
    @RequestMapping(value="/ac477c79d1677a43496823c2a58a2f68sscategoriesMeres",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<SsCategorie>> getSsCategoriesMeres()
       {
       List<SsCategorie> ssCategoriesMeres= ps2.getSsCategoriesMeres();
       if(ssCategoriesMeres!=null)
          return new ResponseEntity<List<SsCategorie>>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
       else
        return new ResponseEntity<List<SsCategorie>>(ssCategoriesMeres,HttpStatus.OK);
     }
```

and the error i am getting is 
angular.js:11442 GET http://localhost:8080/prestaconsult//ac477c79d1677a43496823c2a58a2f68sscategoriesMeres 404 (Not Found)

PS: and i am inserting my angular service and controller to the html.
any suggestions to solve this please?

Comment: The URL you posted has a double slash after prestaconsult, is that intentional?

Comment: Thank y for your answer, I have just seen that, that is an error